# "Edited" Markov Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Given $n$ positive real numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ and their average:
$$m=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$
And I'm required to prove that for any real numbers $t > 1$ this applies:
$$|i\in\{1,2,...,n\}:a_i\ge tm|\le\frac{n}{t}.$$
Or, in words,

- the number (count) of $a_i$ for which $a_i\ge tm$ is satisfied is smaller than $\frac{n}{t}$.

I was given a hint that this is known as Markov Inequation, but when I searched it up the original inequation has something to do with probability, while this one doesn't. Are there any relationships between these two? I would just need a hint.

Is this possible to prove without using probability?

Comment: Do you agree that the inequality is quite trivial ? If you want this one to be related to probability you can take a uniform distribution on the $a_i$s. That's it.

Comment: One more thing: what you wrote in words sounds a bit shaky. $|A|$ denotes the number of elements in the set $A$.

Comment: It is possible to prove this without using probability. I would say even the version $\mathbb P(X>a)\le \frac{\mathbb E(X)}{a}$ has *little* to do with probability theory. Please show *some* own attempts.

Comment: I tried to reorder the average equation to be $n=\frac{1}{m}\sum a_i$. Then I chose all $a_i$ (assume there's X numbers) for which the conditions applies, then $n=\frac{1}{m}\sum a_i \ge Xtm$ or $n \ge Xt$ or $\frac{n}{t} \ge X$. I can't seem to bring $a_i$ in anyhow.

Comment: You still have not picked up on my second comment above what I wrote about $|A|$ and your shaky way of writing $|i\in\{1,...,n\}:a_i\ge tm\}|$ *in words*. I believe that this misunderstanding is the whole problem. No one claims that $a_i\le \frac{n}{t}$ !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Kurt G](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/949989/kurt-g) this is way simpler than I thought.

And to clarify, in the inequality that I was supposed to prove, $|...|$ means the amount of element of the set.

First, the average equation can be rewritten as:

$$n=\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i $$

Assume there are $K$ numbers in $n$ given numbers that satisfy the given condition. Choose $a_k$ as the smallest element from those $K$ numbers. From the sum we choose those K numbers.

Thus we have $$\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i = \frac{1}{m}(a_1+a_2+...+a_n) \ge \frac{1}{m} \underbrace{(a_k + a_k + ... + a_k)}_\text{K times ak} = \frac{1}{m}K\cdot a_k \ge \frac{K}{m}tm=Kt$$
Or $$n\ge Kt \Leftrightarrow K \le \frac{n}{t}. \square$$

Comment: This looks good ! Do you agree that $\mathbb P(X>a)\le\frac{\mathbb E[X]}{a}$ is just as simple that that it isn't really probability theory in the strict sense ? My professor once said: probability theory is measure theory *plus* independence.